# ImportError: cannot import name 'IntType' from 'types'

Tags: python, types, import, package, lib

I get this error for the Timeseries package on Python 3.7.1

```
from types import IntType, LongType, DictType
```

---

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'IntType' from 'types'
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The 3 methods you imported (`IntType, LongType, DictType`) do not exist.

```
>>> import types
>>> dir(types)
['AsyncGeneratorType', 'BuiltinFunctionType', 'BuiltinMethodType', 'CodeType', 'CoroutineType', 'DynamicClassAttribute', 'FrameType', 'FunctionType', 'GeneratorType', 'GetSetDescriptorType', 'LambdaType', 'MappingProxyType', 'MemberDescriptorType', 'MethodType', 'ModuleType', 'SimpleNamespace', 'TracebackType', '_GeneratorWrapper', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_ag', '_calculate_meta', '_collections_abc', '_functools', 'coroutine', 'new_class', 'prepare_class']
>>>
```

As you can see none of the 3 are in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that all types that are already accessible via buildin namesspace are not provided by `types` module (anymore). You can simply use `int` or `dict` from pure python.